# How to compare two files in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created exe using nsis.I have used following code for comparing two files.

```
Function compare 
   IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\old.properties" 0 filenotfound
    FileOpen $0 "$INSTDIR\old.properties" "r"
    FileOpen $1 "$INSTDIR\new.properties" "w"                     
    loop:
        FileRead $0 $2        
        MessageBox MB_OK "old $2" 
        FileRead $1 $3
        MessageBox MB_OK "new $3"                
        IfErrors done                          
        strcmp $3 $2 loop here
        here:                                  
           FileWrite $1 $2                     
           Goto loop
    done:
        FileClose $0                                    
        FileClose $1

     filenotfound:
     MessageBox MB_OK "File not found"
FunctionEnd
```

Read first text of the old property compare first text of the new property if matches go to next word of the both files.else old property values should be replaced in new property file.but if the string mismatches replacing string in the new property file doesnot happen.
How to solve this? what am i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileOpen $1 "$INSTDIR\new.properties" "w"` will erase everything in new.properties, use `"a"` if you want to keep its content.

I don't really fully understand what you are trying to do since "compare files" usually means a read-only operation, you are also writing but you don't seem to actually replace a specific old line with a new different one...

Comment: Thanks."a" mean its append only.i need to replace the values instead of append.The problem is if the user run second time in silent mode it will take default values instead of changed values.so need to compare and write old property values into new property.

Comment: Thanks.I have referred this link http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Replacing_Lines_in_a_Text_File